# Calculator in C - limiting input values

Tags: c, calculator

So I've got an assignment in school, to building a calculator.
The program should consist of a "parcer.c"-file where all the not allowed inputs are sorted out, and if any unallowed values and inputs are submitted it should give you back a "Syntax Error" -message.

i've got it done, only one thing left, and it's this, a if that's supposed to check and make sure that the sizeof (*op) is not bigger than 1, meaning that it can only consist of 1 sign(+,-,*,/,%)
But my problem is that i still can write;
4 +sdf 5 and get the result = 9
But i cant write 4sdf 5 or 4 sdf 5, becuse then I get my "Syntax Error", which is correct.

What should i turn around to give me the same error when I've got junk after the operator?
EX: 4 +sdf 5

```
if(sizeof (*op) > 1 || !validOperator(op))
    {
        //Returns statuscode 2 and a "Syntax Error" if the operator 

          is consisting of more than 1 sign

        printf("\n Syntax Error, only +, -, x, /, %% are allowed\n");
        return 2;
    }
```

Comment: Check and reject if junk exists. Please show us how you read the input.

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Minor: Instead of `printf()` to print a string as a format to `printf()`, use `fputs("\n Syntax Error, only +, -, x, /, % are allowed\n", stdout);`  (%% --> %)

Comment: the input is read as a sscanf function:

Comment: sscanf(argv[2], "%c", op);

Answer (score 1):

I assume op is defined as

```
char *op; /*or maybe as char op[]*/
```

When you check with sizeof(*op) you check the size of the first element in the array of chars, i.e. it will always return 1.

You want to use strlen() instead of sizeof(). Try following change:

```
if( op!=0 && (strlen(*op) > 1 || !validOperator(op)) )
```

Comment: Certainly  you want `if( op!=0 && (strlen(op) > 1...`  (No *)

Comment: is used this and it worked:     if( strlen (argv[2]) > 1

Comment: using the solutions that you guys provided me gave me the same problem as before, but it's probably because something further up in my code, but the above solution works fine, even thou it's ugly